# read temp.txt and write in Mysql Line per line

Tags: python, mysql, file

i have i temp.txt file contain :

36.0
36.0
36.0
36.0
36.0

and i want to read they values with python and write the last line into data base (Mysql) 
Any one can get me one idea how ?
I'm noob in python programming. 
Thank you all

Comment: just start with http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python and tell us if you need some help

Comment: thanks, i also read the document :( but cant resolv my problem, just i want to read the last line ...

Comment: sorry to hear that, but you should at least show us what you tried. we're not going to do your job for you.

Comment: fh = open("hello.txt", "r")
adnen = fh.readline()
print adnen
__________________
this print the first line, and i want to print the last line
thank you for ur answer, but i you cn't help let other peaple help me 
thank you egain

Comment: are they all on one line or are you showing 5 lines?

Comment: at max 1000 lines and always display the last line

Comment: looks good, now you need to make a `for` loop that goes through all lines. just try to `print` them first to make sure you do the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test.txt
"""
36.0
36.0
36.0
36.0
36.0
last line
"""
 with open("test.txt") as f: # use with to close the file automatically
    lines=f.readlines() 
    print lines[-1] # get last element which is the last line
```

Comment: Thank Tou Very much , IS Very Very HelpFull :*

Comment: problem !!!
i read and print the last line, but when i got to insert values into data base i got a big error

 

       import MySQLdb
    with open("temp.txt") as f:
        lines=f.readlines() 
        hum = lines[-1]
        print hum
    while True:
             db  = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","pass","datase");
             cursor = db.cursor()
             cursor.execute("INSERT INTO humidite VALUES(NULL,'%s')",hum)
            print "done"
             db.commit()
             db.rollback()
             db.close()
      time.sleep(30)

Comment: So when execute this appear the problem

> mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '36.0\\n'')' at line 1")

how can i format a hum Value ??

Comment: I think you should post another question with your code and the full traceback.